# c# : Recursive Selection Sort Not Showing any results

Tags: c#, sorting, recursion

pre condition: have an ordered array (From text file) of 1000 integers.

post condition: sort the array of integers using recursive selection sort.

The code is not displaying any results at all. I have added the recursive methods, in the main method I call the RecursiveSelection method.

I have tried making the Recursive method an int and an int[] method but it continues to give no results.

```
public static void RecursiveSelection(int[] Array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array after Recursive Selection Sort: ");

    SelectionSortRecursive(Array, 0); // initial recursive call            
}

private static void SelectionSortRecursive(int[] Array, int n) // sorted in ascending order recursively
{
    if (n >= Array.Length - 1)
        return;
    int min = n;
    for (int i = n+1; i < Array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i] < Array[min])
            min = i;
    }
    swap(Array, n, min);
    SelectionSortRecursive(Array, n + 1);     
}

public static void swap(int[] Array,int x, int y)
{
    int temp = Array[x];
    Array[x] = Array[y];
    Array[y] = temp;
}
```

The output is the `Console.Writeline` statement "Array after Recursive Selection sort..." but nothing else gets displayed. I expected it to display the sorted list.

Comment: where in code do you show output?

Comment: in the main i have :

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < Array.Length; x++)
            {
                RecursiveSelection(Array);
            }

Comment: to display something from your `Array` in console try something like `for (int x = 0; x < Array.Length; x++) { Console.WriteLine(Array[i]); } `

Comment: your `RecursiveSelection` method write only one message in console and nothing about your `Array`

Comment: Thanks I got it... Silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 344, 334, 200, 188, 39, 981, 33 };

        Console.WriteLine("Array after Recursive Selection Sort: ");

        SelectionSortRecursive(array, 0); // initial recursive call

        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void SelectionSortRecursive(int[] Array, int n) // sorted in ascending order recursively
    {
        if (n >= Array.Length - 1)
            return;
        int min = n;
        for (int i = n + 1; i < Array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Array[i] < Array[min])
                min = i;
        }
        swap(Array, n, min);
        SelectionSortRecursive(Array, n + 1);
    }

    public static void swap(int[] Array, int x, int y)
    {
        int temp = Array[x];
        Array[x] = Array[y];
        Array[y] = temp;
    }
}
```

[image: output]